# How to block all special characters and numbers in flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter

How to block all special characters and numbers using regexp?

I know I can allow only [a-zA-Z], but I want to allow Cyrillic or some German characters like ß e.t.c.

How to do this?

Comment: `[^0-9<instert special character list here too>]`

Comment: @Eraklon My fault I want to block numbers too.

Comment: It is blocking numbers atm.

Comment: @Eraklon ok but how to block [$, ", \, '] ?

Comment: `[^0-9"$'\]` some may need to be escaped by \ like `\$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *BlacklistingTextInputFormatter* in TextField

inputFormatters: [
     new BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp('[your regExp for special character]')),
   ],

Comment: Ok, that work but how to block $ or " and '?

Comment: Use this regExp [$"]